# How to display images stored on local file-system in Apache Zeppelin's Markdown interpreter?

Tags: markdown, apache-zeppelin

I can't load and display image files that are stored on my local file-system while working in Zeppelin's MD interpreter. When I serve the same image via a HTTP server it is displayed correctly but not when I use the absolute path for the image.

This is working!:

`![Data Pyramid](http://localhost:8088/images/DIKW_Pyramid.svg.png)`

But this is not showing!:

`![Data Pyramid](/opt/images/DIKW_Pyramid.svg.png)`

Answer (score 1):

The correct path should be `/images/DIKW_Pyramid.svg.png`.

Remember that the URL `http://example.com/` is a request for the path `/` at the domain `http://example.com`. In other words the URL root is the server root.

Servers to not provide access to any part of the host system's files outside of the server root. To do so would be a serious security concern. In fact, if the server root on your system is at `/opt`, then when the server receives a request for `/` it actually looks for `/opt/` on the local file system. Therefore, when the server receives a request for `/opt` it looks for `/opt/opt` which (probably) doesn't exist. You must always start your URL path at the server root regardless of where that directory may be located on the host system.

Comment: Sorry, but I guess there is a misundestanding here, ```/opt/images/DIKW_Pyramid.svg.png``` is an absolute file path on my local machine's file-system and it's not a url for a file being served on a web-server. I checked Github.com flavoured MD and it seems you can load and display an image file from a relative or an absolute path on your file-system.

Comment: Yes there seems to be a misunderstanding on your end. All files need to be served by your server (point your server at the location of the files in the server config). Or you need to use the `file://` protocol. However, if the HTML is being served from your server, then you can't link to an image via `file://` as that would violate the browser's same-source policy (and disabling that policy would create a serious security risk). You could use `file://` for the HTML also, but then you wouldn't be using a server at all, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I guess you mean I cannot load a file just from a file system path, everything to be displayed correctly including an image file should be served on a web-server and one have to use its URI/URL to include it in his/her notebook; please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Aws EMR, zeppelin web app is located at

```
/var/run/zeppelin/webapps/webapp/
```

You can create any folder under this directory to access via Zeppelin notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem. The answer of Waylan is correct and I'm just posting to show a way how you can use the embedded webserver of apache zeppelin to embed your local images with the markdown interpreter.

All you have to do is to store the images inside the Apache Zeppelin webapp folder to embed local images with the markdown interpreter, as those are accessible from outside.

For example when your zeppelin is installed in /opt, just create a directory for the images (but keep in mind that this directory will be deleted everytime you restart Zeppelin):

```sh
mkdir /opt/zeppelin/webapps/webapp/app/markdownImages
```

and store the images there. You can embed them now with the markdown interpreter:

```
![bla](app/markdownImages/test.png)
```